# How can I make ASP MVC localization routes without interfering with AngularJS routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-routing

I'm starting a project with ASP MVC and AngularJS, I would like to have ASP MVC to handle the localization from within the URL as something like this: `http://localhost:4416/en/#/contact` or this `http://localhost:4416/en-US/#/home` and so the localization is set before the hash tag and I want ASP MVC Route to handle it because I also use Razor for the View pages. In a previous project of ASP MVC only, I had this type of Routes to handle language and culture:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new
      {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        language = "en",
        culture = "CA"
      }
  );
```

and in AngularJS my first testing routes are these:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    //Setup routes to load partial templates from server. 
    //TemplateUrl is the location for the server view (Razor .cshtml view)
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })
        .when('/contact', { templateUrl: '/home/contact', controller: 'ContactController' })
        .when('/about', { templateUrl: '/home/about', controller: 'AboutController' })
        .when('/demo', { templateUrl: '/home/demo', controller: 'DemoController' })
        .when('/angular', { templateUrl: '/home/angular' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);
```

As a side note, removing the `{language}` from the ASP `routes.MapRoute` and passing a regular URL of `http://localhost:4416/#/contact` does work but without any localization handling. So typically what I would use is a language route in the URL (which will always be there and is to be found before the hash tag). 

Oh and just as reference, I based myself on the [AngularStart](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b) project, which I updated all packages to be ASP.MVC5, EF6, AngularJS 1.2.23

**Edit**
I know that my `Global.asax.cs` file gets trigger twice, the first time it does take the language from my URL as I maee a default address in my project property but then what's happening is that AngularJS trigger kicks in and then re-route to default `/home` because of the otherwise. I'm assuming that I would probably have to put something inside the Angular code to handle the language, but what do I need to put is not clear to me...

Answer (score 0):

After a certain time, I manage to get big part of it working (except html5mode). So if we stick with hash tag, it's all working... Let see the code

Angular app declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ngGrid', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);     //Define the main module

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      //Setup routes to load partial templates from server. TemplateUrl is the location for the server view (Razor .cshtml view)
      $routeProvider
          .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/main', controller: 'MainController' })
          .when('/contact', { templateUrl: '/home/contact', controller: 'ContactController' })
          .when('/about', { templateUrl: '/home/about', controller: 'AboutController' })
          .when('/demo', { templateUrl: '/home/demo', controller: 'DemoController' })
          .when('/angular', { templateUrl: '/home/angular' })
          .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }]);
```

The `Shared\_Layout.cshtml` code

```
<head>
    <base id="basePath" href="/@((ViewContext.RouteData.Values["language"] != null) ? ViewContext.RouteData.Values["language"] : "en")/" />  
</head>

<body>
    <!-- the rest of your bootstrap navbar code here... -->
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href='' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href='#/home'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/demo">Demo</a></li>
          <li><a href='#/angular'>Learn Angular</a></li>
          <li><a href='#/about'>About</a></li>
          <li><a href='#/contact'>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</body>
```

The `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` code

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new
          {
            language = "en",
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,            
            culture = "CA"
          },
          constraints: new { language = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}$" }
      );

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "DefaultWithoutLang",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new
          {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
          }
      );
    }
}
```

then finally inside `Global.asax` file, I added this new function

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string connectedUsername = "";
  if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    connectedUsername = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
  }

  var handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
  var routeData = handler != null ? handler.RequestContext.RouteData : null;

  var routeCulture = (routeData != null && routeData.Values.ContainsKey("language")) ? routeData.Values["language"].ToString() : null;
  var phpsessionid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["PHPSESSID"];
  var languageCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["language"];
  var userLanguages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

  // Set the Culture based on a route, a cookie or the browser settings,
  // or default value if something went wrong
  var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(
      routeCulture ?? (
          languageCookie != null
             ? languageCookie.Value
             : userLanguages != null
                 ? userLanguages[0]
                 : "en")
  );

  // save language in a cookie (fr, en, es, ...)
  var langCookie = new HttpCookie("language", cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(langCookie);

  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
}
```

So it's all working except html5mode as specified earlier. If someone can help me out on that too, I would be happy...   I read somewhere that I might need a middleware to catch 404 and transform it somehow, but I don't quite understand that part.

Feel free to correct my code if any errors are spotted (still new in ASP and Angular).